# Changing one part of code affects the other part when compiling with use_fast_math flag

Tags: cuda

I have the following kernel:

```
__global__ void kernel()
{
  float loc{269.0f};
  float s{(356.0f - loc) / 13.05f};

  float a{pow(1.0f - 0.15f * s, 1.0f)};
  float b{pow(1.0f - 0.15f * (356.0f - loc) / 13.05f, 1.0f)};

  printf("%f\n", a);
  printf("%f\n", b);
}
```

It prints

```
0.000000
0.000000
```

But if I change how `b` is calculated:

```
__global__ void kernel()
{
  float loc{269.0f};
  float s{(356.0f - loc) / 13.05f};

  float a{pow(1.0f - 0.15f * s, 1.0f)};
  float b{pow(1.0f - 0.15f * ((356.0f - loc) / 13.05f), 1.0f)}; // notice the added braces

  printf("%f\n", a);
  printf("%f\n", b);
}
```

it prints:

```
nan
nan
```

Why does adding the braces for `b` change `a` as well? Why do the braces have an effect at all? Looking at the code on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/5rvhMhhnb) I see that the generated assembly is different, but I don't have enough knowledge to understand what exactly causes this behavior.

This is my project configuration:

```
set_target_properties(test PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 14
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES
    CXX_EXTENSIONS NO
    CUDA_STANDARD 14
    CUDA_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES
    CUDA_EXTENSIONS NO
    CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON
    CUDA_ARCHITECTURES "61"
)

set(CUDA_FLAGS --use_fast_math)
set(CXX_FLAGS -O0)
```

Please notice the flag `--use_fast_math` - without it, everything works fine.
My GPU is Quadro P1000.
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.2, V11.2.152.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is **not numerically stable**: it contains a [**catastrophic cancellation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_cancellation). Indeed, `1.0f - 0.15f * s` and `1.0f - 0.15f * ((356.0f - loc) / 13.05f)` are nearly equal to 0. It can be equal to few unit in the last place (ULP). Regarding the rounding, the value can be positive, negative or 0. **When the base value is negative, the result of pow is undefined**. The thing is the rounding is dependent of the compiler **heuristic** since you explicitly enabled fast-math that disable some IEEE-754 rules like taking care of the floating-point associativity and the possible presence of NaN values. With fast-math, the compiler is free to use **approximations** like a reciprocal (less accurate) instead of the basic division. In fact it actually do that in your case. Consequently, results are undefined and the compiler is free to set the output to 0 or NaN regarding its heuristic. I think that having a pow exponent set to 1.0f (which is well represented) does not save you from this behaviour with [`pow`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__DOUBLE.html#group__CUDA__MATH__DOUBLE) (note you should use `powf` for `float` values and not `pow` which is for `double` values.

The proper way to solve this issue is to **use a stable numerical computation** that do not contains any catastrophic cancellation like in your code. The actual solution is very dependent of the overall computational method. Sometime, one need to use a completely different algorithm (eg. QR factorization instead of LU factorization, 2 step variance computation instead of a 1 step one).

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation, it explains why there's `nan` in the result and how the presence of braces has an effect on the `b`'s calculation. But I asked one more thing -  if you look closely at the computation of `a`, you'll see that it's the same for both cases, though its result is dependent on how `b` was calculated.

Comment: Compilers use an optimization called [common subexpression elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination) so to optimize math expression like yours. Because `--use_fast_math` is used, the parenthesis does no matter (as long as they are mathematically equivalent, though not numerically). As a result, a change in the computation of a shared sub-expression in `a` can impact `b` and vice-versa. Here, I expect the compiler to compute the whole expression once.

Comment: Note that compiler heuristics can have a different behaviour regarding unrelated changes. This is (unfortunately) quite frequent with GCC and ICC. This can cause some obscure behaviour like adding a printf (in a condition never true) which surprisingly speed up a program. Function inlining, alignments and the code layout are particularly affected by this heuristic.